# iText table rowspan for right to left direction(Arabic)

Tags: itext

My application is developed in two different version English and Arabic.
I have created pdf table in iText with rowspan and colspan which is working perfectly in English version but in arabic version rowspan is not working.
when i'm using setRunDirection(3) to put arabic text in my table,the setRowspan(2) is not working.

please tell me how set rowspan value here.

please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

This is part of code for table size 2 column and rowspan 2.

```
BaseFont base=BaseFont.createFont("C:/Windows/Font/arial.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font sourceFont= new Font(base, 9,Font.NORMAL,Color.RED);
PdfPTable tab1=new PdfPTable(2);
tab1.setRunDirection(3);//**(if you comment this line it will work)**
PdfPCell cells;
cells=new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("arabic text", sourceFont));
cells.setRowspan(2);
tab1.addCell(cells);
cells=new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("arabic text", sourceFont));
tab1.addCell(cells);
cells=new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("arabic text", sourceFont));
tab1.addCell(cells);
```

Comment: I'm using iTextSharp which is the .Net port of iText and is pretty much the exact same. I just created a `PdfPTable` with two columns and added a `PdfPCell` with Arabic text that spans two rows and it seems to be working just font. I'm using version 5.1.1.0. Can you provide some code and specify which version you are targeting?

Comment: i have posted my code.please take a look....

Comment: Try setting the run direction on the `PdfPCell` itself instead of the whole table `cells.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);`

Comment: In arabic table should start from right to left.first we need table direction and then cell direction to display text inside cell from right to left.

Comment: For a workaround on this issue, I've used MinimumHeight = 100 for this cell and removed RowSpan. This should look like rowspan effect.

Comment: I have the exact same issue in my android application. I'm using itext 5.5.10.

Answer (score 0):

When I use `table.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL)`  RowSpan is NotWorking!
so I Remove This Line And Add this:

```
PdfPCell title_cell= new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("متن عربی"));
title_cell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
table.addCell(title_cell);
```

My Table have 6 column and 5 Rows. Right cell in First Row is rowspan 5.
My Code here:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] {10,10,10,10,10,50});
table_mehr.setTotalWidth(PageSize.A4.getWidth()-30);
table_mehr.setLockedWidth(true);
table_mehr.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            PdfPCell title_cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("متن عربی"));
            title_cell.setRowspan(5);
            title_cell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);

            table.addCell(title_cell);
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            table.addCell("ali");
            doc.add(table);
```