# In iText, how to set the rowspan of a right-columned table cell?

Tags: java, itext

I need to draw a table like this.

```
---------------
|  A   |   C  |
|------|      |
|  B   |      |
---------------
```

The following code does not work. It creates a table with a single row, without drawing the 'C' cell:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.addCell("A");
table.addCell("B");
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("C"));
cell.setRowspan(2);
table.addCell(cell);
```

Drawing the opposite table (with the rowspanning cell on the left) works just fine.

I have noticed a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804585/itext-table-rowspan-for-right-to-left-directionarabic), but the context is different (I am not working on an international app) so I think I can rephrase the question again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tables are always drawn left to right, top to bottom, so you need to add `A`, then `C` and then finally `B`.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.addCell("A");
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("C"));
cell.setRowspan(2);
table.addCell(cell);
table.addCell("B");
```

iText requires that all cells in a table are accounted for. If any cells are missing it skips that entire row. Your original code added `A` to R1C1, then `B` to R1C2, then created a new row and added a single cell to it, which, since it was a widow got trimmed off.

Comment: This way of handling the addition of cells in which the number of cells in a row must match the number of columns defined in the table; otherwise the row is trimmed of... man this is not good! :) I was going crazy and trying every wording in a Google Search to understand why my last row was not being added to the table. My row has only one left column (an image) and your explanation was to the point. I'll have to add some math to handle this since the number of rows is dynamic - I can have 3, 5, 7... cells. You're the man when it comes to iText. Congrats and thank you once more. God bless.

Comment: I did this to solve my specific problem in the case of an odd number of cells: `if (chapterAnswersGroups.Count() % 2 != 0)
            {
                pdfTable.AddCell(string.Empty);
            }`

Answer (score 3):

You should use nested tables:

```
PdfPTable inner = new PdfPTable(1);
inner.addCell("A");
inner.addCell("B");

PdfPTable outer = new PdfPTAble(2);
outer.addCell(inner);
outer.addCell("C");
```